# How do I get a .minecraft folder

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, technical-issues, windows

I do NOT have a .minecraft folder in %appdata%/roaming. So how do I get a .minecraft folder. I've seen other questions like this and you guys just told people why they don't have one. So I'd like to know how I can get one. So do ***NOT*** just tell me why I don't have one.

Comment: *We guys* love it when complete strangers demand help in their specific way for non-issues.

Comment: If you cant see any, its very probable that you just play an edition that doesn't have one. I think only the original java version does. Those that are within the Microsoft store do not.

Answer (score 2):

You can't get one if you are using bedrock, and mods from java (where you probably got the mod from) wouldn't be compatible anyway.